# Angularfire2 I'm trying to get the field names of a angular fire document

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular7

I have a firebase collection called 'post' with one document called 'test1' I'm trying to read the field names of the 'test1' document and place them in an array. But I have no idea how to go about since I just started learning firebase and it's quite different from my SQL experience.

Here is my constructor

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private dialog: MatDialog) {
this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('posts');
this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return {id, ...data};
  })));
}
```

[image of my firebase collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmWc2.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.